# take a string from another worksheet and turn into date format

Tags: vba

I have looked up many questions similar to mine but there is a big difference. The string I am trying to format in VBA excel doesn't have any dots or hyphens. my string is parsed from another sheet in the file and it goes through the sheet for multiple lines so each time it runs through the for loop it gives a different date in a string similar to this: "11271998". I need to put it in short date format or to look like this "MM/DD/YYYY". Once in this format it needs to be placed in another worksheet. I have tried dim as date but it gives me an error. I think I need to make a function and call it but I am not sure how to use mid or split to separate the string 3 times. Please help.
 Here is my code:

```
        Sub First()
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Entries As Integer, Age As Integer
  Dim Name() As String, Lastname As String, Firstname As String, Group As String, Bdate As String
  Dim BSCswim(42)
  Dim LSC As String, Contact As String, Team As String, LastnameC() As String
  Dim Entrants() As swimmerData
  With Worksheets("BSC")
    Entries = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count - 2
  End With
  ReDim Entrants(Entries)
  For i = 0 To Entries
    BSCswim(i) = Worksheets("BSC").Range("A1").Offset(i).Value
  Next i
  LSC = Mid(BSCswim(2), 12, 5)
  Team = Mid(BSCswim(2), 12, 30)
  For j = 3 To Entries Step 2
    Entrants(j).Fullname = Mid(BSCswim(j), 12, 28)
    Name = Split(Entrants(j).Fullname)
    Lastname = Name(0)
    Firstname = Name(1)
    LastnameC() = Split(Lastname, ",")
    Entrants(j).DOB = Mid(BSCswim(j), 56, 8)
    Entrants(j).Age = Mid(BSCswim(j), 64, 2)
    Age = Entrants(j).Age
    Group = AgeGroup(Age)
    Entrants(j).Gender = Mid(BSCswim(j), 66, 1)
    Entrants(j).event = Mid(BSCswim(j), 68, 4)
    Entrants(j).MemNum = Mid(BSCswim(j), 40, 12)
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("B2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Firstname
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("C2").Offset(j - 3).Value = LastnameC(0)
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("D2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Entrants(j).Fullname
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("E2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Entrants(j).Gender
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("F2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Entrants(j).DOB
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("G2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Group
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("H2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Age
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("I2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Entrants(j).MemNum
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("J2").Offset(j - 3).Value = Team
    Worksheets("Entries").Range("K2").Offset(j - 3).Value = LSC
Next j
End Sub
Function AgeGroup(ByRef Age As Integer)
Dim AgeG As String

   If Age <= 10 Then
          AgeG = "10 and Under"
     ElseIf Age = 11 Or Age = 12 Then
              AgeG = "11-12"
        ElseIf Age = 13 Or Age = 14 Then
                 AgeG = "13-14"
          ElseIf Age >= 15 And Age <= 18 Then
                    AgeG = "15-19"
                    ElseIf Age >= 19 And Age <= 24 Then
                      AgeG = "20-24"
                      ElseIf Age >= 25 And Age <= 29 Then
                         AgeG = "25-29"
                         ElseIf Age >= 30 And Age <= 34 Then
                            AgeG = "30-34"
                            ElseIf Age >= 35 And Age <= 39 Then
                                AgeG = "35-39"
                              ElseIf Age >= 40 And Age <= 44 Then
                                   AgeG = "40-44"
                                   ElseIf Age >= 45 And Age <= 49 Then
                                     AgeG = "45-49"
                                     ElseIf Age >= 50 And Age <= 54 Then
                                       AgeG = "50-54"
                                       ElseIf Age >= 55 And Age <= 59 Then
                                         AgeG = "55-59"
                                         ElseIf Age >= 60 And Age <= 64 Then
                                           AgeG = "60-64"
                                           Else
                                           AgeG = "65-69"
                                           End If

      AgeGroup = AgeG

    End Function
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

This will save the date to the next column to the right of the original date. If this gives you the format you are looking for then you just need to save it where you want it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call DateConverter
End Sub
Public Function DateConverter()
Dim rng As Range
Dim NewDate As Date

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")

For Each cell In rng
    NewDate = Mid(cell, 5, 2) & "/" & Right(cell, 2) & "/" & Left(cell, 4)
    cell.Offset(0, 1) = NewDate
Next cell

End Function
```